# Why jquery datable is showing the old records instead of the new one being picked?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatables

I have the datatable being filled by the viewmodel on page load. That's ok.

Now I want to fill it with one record upon clicking the dropdown. But the datatable shows old records instead of the new one being picked.

I tried this:

```
        table = $("#tblCertificates").DataTable();

        $.get("/CertificatesNew/FillCertificates", data);

        table.clear();
```

but not working. I want to make the jquery datatable empty before refilling with new data.

```
 [HttpGet]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0)]
        public ActionResult FillCertificates(int ID)
        {
            InspectionReportsViewModel InspectionReportsViewModel = new InspectionReportsViewModel();

            try
            {

                InspectionReportDAL InspectionReportDAL = new DAL.InspectionReportDAL();
                InspectionReportsViewModel.InspectionReportList = InspectionReportDAL.GetInspectionReportListFilteredByClientID(ID);

                ClientsDAL clientsDAL = new ClientsDAL();

                ViewBag.ClientsList = clientsDAL.GetClientsList();

                return View("Index", InspectionReportsViewModel); 
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
```

api call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#tblCertificates').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            searching: true,
            ordering: false,

        });

        $("#SearchInspectionReport_Client_ID").change(function () {
            var ID = $("#SearchInspectionReport_Client_ID").val(); //Client ID



            //if(!Number(ID)) // to check if '-Select-' has been selected, so in that case it should be stopped from further execution
            //{
            //    $("#InspectionReport_PoNo").val('');
            //}

            data = { 'ID': ID } //Client ID

            table = $("#tblCertificates").DataTable();
            //oSettings = table.fnSettings();



            $.get("/CertificatesNew/FillCertificates", data);

            table.clear();
        });

    </script>
}
```

table:

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach (var InspectionReport in this.Model.InspectionReportList)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <td>@InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo</td>
                            <td>@InspectionReport.VelosiReportNo</td>
                            <td style="@(@InspectionReport.Status == 0 ? "Background-color: lightblue" : @InspectionReport.Status == 1 ? "Background-color:skyblue" : @InspectionReport.Status == 2 ? "Background-color: lightgray" : @InspectionReport.Status == 3 ? "Background-color: #99CC99" : @InspectionReport.Status == 4 ? "Background-color: #FF3333" : "")">
                                @(@InspectionReport.Status == 0 ? "Prepared" : @InspectionReport.Status == 1 ? "Reviewed" : @InspectionReport.Status == 2 ? "Approved" : @InspectionReport.Status == 3 ? "Issued" : @InspectionReport.Status == 4 ? "Rejected" : "")
                            </td>

                            <td>@InspectionReport.InspectionDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")</td>
                            <td>@InspectionReport.IssueDate.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy")</td>

                            @{ 
                               VAILCertificates.DAL.UserDAL userDAL = new VAILCertificates.DAL.UserDAL();
                               VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities.User User = new VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities.User();
                               User = userDAL.GetUserStationLocation(InspectionReport.PeparedBy);                              
                             }

                            <td>@User.UserName</td>     
                            <td>@User.Office</td>
                            <td>@User.Station</td> 

                            <td>
                                @using (Html.BeginForm("GetInspectionReportDetails", "InspectionReport", FormMethod.Post, new { InspectionReportID = @InspectionReport.InspectionReportID }))
                                {
                                    @*@Html.ActionLink("View", "Edit","InspectionReport", new { id = @InspectionReport.InspectionReportID }, new { @Class = "btn btn-success" })*@
                                    @*@Html.ActionLink("View", "GetInspectionReportDetails","InspectionReport", new { id = @InspectionReport.InspectionReportID }, new { @Class = "btn btn-success" })*@
                                    <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="btnReview" name="btnDownload" formaction='@Url.Action("GetInspectionReportDetails", "InspectionReport", new { InspectionReportID = @InspectionReport.InspectionReportID})'>Download Files</button>
                                    @*<a class="btn btn-primary" href="@("/Downloads/Certificates/"+ @InspectionReport.FileName)" download>Download Certificate</a>*@

                                }
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: Can't you just use ```$("td").text('')```?
That should empty all the cells. Then call the api again and fill in data again.

Comment: $('#tblCertificates tbody').empty();